# CVE-2020-36518 : Unable to resolve WhiteSource vulnerability for jackson-databind library

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, whitesource

I have tried all the versions of **jackson-databind** (including version suggested on whitesource fix), but all the version for jackson-databind showing vulnerability on whitesource scan.

Below is the description of the issue and we can also see the WhiteSource Note :
[image]

Can someone help me here to resolve this?

Note: I am using jackson-databind dependency so can not exclude it in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

The fix for it on the way. Thanks to the open source community. In mean time if there  is possibility of a waiver, please request from your vendor.

More details can be found at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2816